# Broken table in "Ask like a human: Implementing semantic search on Stack Overflow" blog post

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, tables

In the blog post titled [Ask like a human: Implementing semantic search on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/07/31/ask-like-a-human-implementing-semantic-search-on-stack-overflow/), there is ... this:

> [image]

Not sure what that was intended to be, but that's not easy to read. Can that be cleaned up a bit? Specifically, I'd suggest

- Disclaimer gets moved to a new line
- The two headings and the links be converted to a table (or possibly two ordered lists?)

Comment: Ah yes, that is exactly like a human.

Comment: Too many spaces. Not human enough.

Comment: I found [an archived version of the page on the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20230801014326/https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/07/31/ask-like-a-human-implementing-semantic-search-on-stack-overflow/), showing what the table is supposed to look like. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: @V2Blast I totally understand if not, but it'd be great if when you (or someone else at SE) fixes it, they could also fix [these errors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392440/errors-in-blog-post-ask-like-a-human-implementing-semantic-search-on-stack-ove), as it's the same blog post. Thank you!

Comment: These issues, along with the ones reported in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392440/208518), have been fixed.